# Upload file to Azure

Tags: c#, azure

I want to upload a file in azure using C#.net no matter what format it will be. I want to check whether the file exists or not. If it exists then create a folder dynamically to save the uploaded file.

How can I pass another parameter which will check if the uploaded file exists or not, then if it exists, then create a subfolder in the `Uploads` folder to save it?

```
public UploadedFile Upload(Stream Uploading)
{
    try
    {
        string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png";
        string FilePath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Uploads"), filename);

        UploadedFile upload = new UploadedFile
        {
            FilePath = FilePath
        };

        int length = 0;
        using (FileStream writer = new FileStream(upload.FilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            int readCount;
            var buffer = new byte[8192];
            while ((readCount = Uploading.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                writer.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                length += readCount;
            }
        }
        upload.FileLength = length;

        return new UploadedFile { FilePath = "/Uploads/" + filename };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error("Error Occured in Upload", ex);
        ErrorData errorData = new ErrorData("Error Occured ", ex.Message);
        throw new WebFaultException<ErrorData>(errorData, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: look at this link [BlobStorageUploadProvider](http://arcware.net/upload-and-download-files-with-web-api-and-azure-blob-storage/) you need to scroll halfway down on the page and search the page for `BlobStorageUploadProvider`

Answer (score 1):

Before you upload the file check if the same file name exists in the path. You can check if file exists using below code

```
//Read the path of your file
    string curFile = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
    Console.WriteLine(File.Exists(curFile) ? "File exists." : "File does not exist.");
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks,bt how can I save by creating a folder dynamically.